# Morphia and object graphs

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I've yet to use Morphia, but I'm considering it for a current project.

Suppose I have a POJO with a number of @Reference annotations and I ask Morphia to fetch the object graph from the database.  If I then make another DAO or DataStore call and ask Morphia to fetch some object that was already instantiated in the first graph, would Morphia return a reference to the already instantiated object or would it create a new instance?

If Morphia returns a new instance of the object each time, does anyone have a recommendation of how to best approach creating a Morphia-backed repository that won't duplicate already-instantiated objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see it in Morphia, it will re read every reference.
This is one of the problems, why I created [Morphium](http://code.google.com/p/morphium/). I integrated a caching layer there, so if you read a reference, this one won't be read again (at least, if you search by ID...)

Answer (score 1):

We use morphia in production and there are two ways to make sure you don't load the references which is something we came across too.

One is to use the lazy loading option when you define the @Reference element in your main class.  This of course means that this behavior is 'global' to that object.

The better way to do this is to not define an @Reference using Morphia and instead managing the references yourself.  Let me know if you need a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

I've stopped using @Reference too and instead declare something like:

```
 ObjectId itemId
```

rather than having a field item. This has 2 benefits: (1) it lets me define a getter through  a helper getObject(...) method which I have written with object caching and (2) it stores a simple ObjectId in the Mongo object rather than a full DBRef which includes the collection name and thus about twice the data size.